# Javascript Books challenge

Tags: javascript, promise

I tried to complete a javascript assessment for a job interview but failed

My plan was to process the user object inside findPotentialLikes function but it'll always throw undefined.

It is made using Mocha and Chai testing framework and promises.

Basically my question is: how do i get the user in the findPotentialLikes promise ?

```
class SocialNetworkQueries {

    constructor({ fetchCurrentUser }) {
        this.fetchCurrentUser = fetchCurrentUser;
    }

    findPotentialLikes({ minimalScore } = { }) {
        
     console.log(this.fetchCurentUser);
     // I tried here to get the user in order to process the findPotentialLikes function with no luck

        return Promise.resolve();
        
    }

}


describe('SocialNetworkQueries', () => {
  describe("example from README", () => {

    it("should find potential likes", async () => {
      // given
      const user = {
        id: "mrouk3",
        likes: {
          books: ["Moby Dick", "Ulysses"],
        },
        friends: [{
          id: "YazL",
          likes: {
            books: ["Ulysses", "War and Peace"],
          }
        }],
      };

      // when
      const potentialLikes = await new SocialNetworkQueries({
        fetchCurrentUser: () => Promise.resolve(user),
      }).findPotentialLikes({ minimalScore: 0.3 });

      // then
      expect(potentialLikes).toEqual({
        books: [
          "The Great Gatsby",
          "Don Quixote",
          "War and Peace",
        ],
      });
    });

  });
});
```

Comment: Could you replace your comment in `findPotentialLikes` with the actual code you tried?

Comment: I actually ran out of time just trying to fetch the user before writing any code

Comment: The tests as presented do not provide enough context - the test data is insufficient to derive the asserted value (e.g. nowhere in the test user data do the book titles `"The Great Gatsby"` and `"Don Quixote"` appear). That said, you'd need to `const user = await this.fetchCurrentUser()` in order to retrieve the user value resolved from the promise.

Answer (score 1):

Given that the `fetchCurrentUser` argument is provided by the test as a function which returns a promise which resolves to a user value, you would need to retrieve the resolved value from the promise, either via async/await:

```js
class SocialNetworkQueries {
    constructor({ fetchCurrentUser }) {
        this.fetchCurrentUser = fetchCurrentUser;
    }

    async findPotentialLikes({ minimalScore } = { }) {
        const user = await this.fetchCurrentUser();

        // ...

        return {
            books: [
                "The Great Gatsby",
                "Don Quixote",
                "War and Peace",
            ]
        };
    }
}
```

or logic in a `.then()` callback which will execute after the user has resolved:

```js
class SocialNetworkQueries {
    constructor({ fetchCurrentUser }) {
        this.fetchCurrentUser = fetchCurrentUser;
    }

    findPotentialLikes({ minimalScore } = { }) {
        return this.fetchCurrentUser().then(
            user => {
                // ...

                return {
                    books: [
                        "The Great Gatsby",
                        "Don Quixote",
                        "War and Peace",
                    ]
                };
            }
        );
    }
}
```

Either approach is functionally equivalent and results in `findPotentialLikes()` returning a Promise which resolves with the asserted value from the test.